# Can't shrink Windows Boot NTFS disk: ERROR(5): Could not map attribute 0x80 in inode, Input/output error

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, gparted

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, all updates current as of 7/3/2012

gksudo gparted
Shrink /dev/sda2 from 367GB to 307GB

```
GParted 0.11.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid

Libparted 2.3

Shrink /dev/sda2 from 367.00 GiB to 307.00 GiB  00:32:57    ( ERROR )

calibrate /dev/sda2  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sda2
start: 20,484,096
end: 790,142,975
size: 769,658,880 (367.00 GiB)
check file system on /dev/sda2 for errors and (if possible) fix them  00:00:53    ( SUCCESS )

ntfsresize -P -i -f -v /dev/sda2

ntfsresize v2012.1.15AR.1 (libntfs-3g)
Device name : /dev/sda2
NTFS volume version: 3.1
Cluster size : 4096 bytes
Current volume size: 394065338880 bytes (394066 MB)
Current device size: 394065346560 bytes (394066 MB)
Checking for bad sectors ...
Checking filesystem consistency ...
Accounting clusters ...
Space in use : 327950 MB (83.2%)
Collecting resizing constraints ...
Estimating smallest shrunken size supported ...
File feature Last used at By inode
$MFT : 389998 MB 0
Multi-Record : 394061 MB 386464
$MFTMirr : 314823 MB 1
Compressed : 394064 MB 1019521
Sparse : 330887 MB 752454
Ordinary : 393297 MB 706060
You might resize at 327949758464 bytes or 327950 MB (freeing 66116 MB).
Please make a test run using both the -n and -s options before real resizing!
shrink file system  00:32:04    ( ERROR )

run simulation  00:32:04    ( ERROR )

ntfsresize -P --force --force /dev/sda2 -s 329640837119 --no-action

ntfsresize v2012.1.15AR.1 (libntfs-3g)
Device name : /dev/sda2
NTFS volume version: 3.1
Cluster size : 4096 bytes
Current volume size: 394065338880 bytes (394066 MB)
Current device size: 394065346560 bytes (394066 MB)
New volume size : 329640829440 bytes (329641 MB)
Checking filesystem consistency ...
Accounting clusters ...
Space in use : 327950 MB (83.2%)
Collecting resizing constraints ...
Needed relocations : 13300525 (54479 MB)
Schedule chkdsk for NTFS consistency check at Windows boot time ...
Resetting $LogFile ... (this might take a while)
Relocating needed data ...
Updating $BadClust file ...
Updating $Bitmap file ...
ERROR(5): Could not map attribute 0x80 in inode 1667593: Input/output error
========================================
```

Windows has run chkdsk successfully (on boot) several times now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So what I eventually did to resize it was to resize in increments

First resize, shrink by 5GB, then tried by an additional 10GB, 25GB, and 20GB until it got down to the desired size.

Not entirely sure why gparted gives an error when it tries to do it all at once, but seems like this strategy works.

Probably the same technique that @TylerH used (by setting shrink size to 10% larger than before)

Answer (score 5):

I had similar error to this while trying to shrink a 931GB partition to about 600GB when the partition had 555TB used.

The attempt to shrink directly to 600GB failed as did an attempt to shrink to 610GB.

I then chose the mid point between 610GB and 931GB = 731GB and was able to get past the simulation check. If this works, I will keep trying mid points until I get to the size I need to get to.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this problem today.

1. After experiencing the issue, I ran a chkdisk, a thorough disk cleanup and then defragemented.
2. When I tried again to create the partition I added an additional 10% of the stated minimum size of the partition (according to gparted). So it was just under 110% of the minimum size because I wanted a nice round number.

Perhaps one or a combination of these items will help solve the issue for you as well.

Comment: Create the partition? Did you reformat or something? Did you use gparted or the windows?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't provide full background on my approach.  I was resizing a partition at the time I ran into this error.  After successfully resizing I created a new partition with the space created by the resize.  Hence my wording.  But that should be unrelated to the issue here.

So, in **resizing**, i added 10% more space compared to my previous attempts.  Which was successful.

Comment: Please do not create a new answer. Instead, click the Edit link below your previous answer to add details. Even with 1 rep, you can edit your own posts.

Comment: To add to what @ObsessiveFOSS said, please note that if you find you cannot edit your answer, make sure you're logged in with the same user account you used to post it. You can also request that your user accounts be merged. One way to request this is to post on [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/).